# flexbox: CSS boxes not displaying properly

Tags: html, css, flexbox

just started a tutorial on flexbox,
this is their code: https://jsfiddle.net/bradtraversy/bu0ecodm/1/

I tried creating a really basic google. For some reason, the boxes and containers aren't displaying properly. No matter how much I change the padding or border size/color nothing changes

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="google-code.css">
  <script src="google-code.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  
  <div class="left-container">
    <div class="icon-box">
      <h3> google </h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="middle-container">
    <div class="search-box">
      <h1>search</h1>
    <div class="tools-box">
      <h1>tools</h1>
    </div>
    </div>
 </div>

  <div class="right-container">
  </div>



</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.left-container{
  display:flex;
}
.left-container div{

  border: 1px #ccc solid;
  padding: 10px;
}

.middle-container{
  display:flex;
}
.middle-container div{
  border: 1px #ccc solid;
  padding: 30px;
}
.search-box{
  flex:1;
  order:2;
}
.tools-box{
  flex:2;
  order:1;
}
```

This is what's displayed:
[image]

This is what I expected:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is a great resource on how flex-box works:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

But I think this more closely matches what you are looking for according to your drawing.

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="google-code.css">
      <script src="google-code.js"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
      <div class='flex-box'>
          <div class="left-container">
          <div class="icon-box">
            <h3> google </h3>
          </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="middle-container">
          <div class="search-box">
            <h1>search</h1>
          </div>
           <div class="tools-box">
            <h1>tools</h1>
          </div>
       </div>
      </div>

    
    
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.flex-box{
display:flex;
}

.left-container > div{

border: 1px #ccc solid;
padding: 10px;
}

.middle-container{
display:flex;
flex-direction:column;
border: 1px #ccc solid;
width:100%;
}

.middle-container > div{
border: 1px #ccc solid;
margin: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
}

.search-box{
order:1;
}
.tools-box{
order:2;
}
```

**DISPLAY**

[Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lawBY.png)

Comment: Just found out that it was my text editor that wouldn't display anything properly.. May I ask what you code with?

Comment: For this, I just used JSfiddle. But Brackets is great for HTML, CSS, and Javascript as it gives you a live preview of what the elements will look like as you go. 
http://brackets.io/

Answer (score 2):

There, only changed in your `HTML`

```
<body>
    <div class="left-container">
        <div class="icon-box">
            <h3> google </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="icon-box">  <!-- HERE -->
            <div class="middle-container">
                <div class="search-box">
                    <h1>search</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="middle-container">
                <div class="tools-box">
                    <h1>tools</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-container">
    </div>
</body>
```

**NOTE:**

Try to name your `CSS` classes meaningfully, and don't repeat them when they have different names but same attributes actually, so for example: `.left-container` & `.middle-container` are the same, why don't you just call them **`row`**, same for your `.search-box` & `.tools-box`, why don't you call them **`col`**.

In my case i just renamed the classes until i solve this out, and i was like, so we've got a row with 2 columns, and inside the second column, we've got 2 rows, each row has 1 column inside of it, and that was it!

**Another NOTE:**

If you want to make the `search` & `tools` stretch to the end, just wrap them with a `col` class. (in your case just change `icon-box` in your html to either `search-box` or `tools-box`). I added a comment next to it, it says "HERE".

Hope this helped.

Answer (score -1):

If you gave the body tag the display: flex; property, it should put Google and (tools + search) on the same line. Should give you something like this,
[image]

Comment: Yes, this is how I wanted it displayed. I added: body{display:flex;} to the top of the CSS code but nothing changed

Comment: You can force flex direction by doing, flex-direction: row;, though the default should just be row flex direction